# can someone help me out for converting string to object in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str="Segment Id : 82394 | Segment Name : SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (Permission)_01 | Segment 
        Count : 0 Segment Id : 82395 |
        Segment Name : SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (LeadYoung)_02 | Segment Count : 0
        Segment Id : 82395 | 
        Segment Name : SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (LeadYoung)_02 | Segment Count : 0"
```

I want to convert this into an object like

```
[{    
SegmentId : 82394,    
SegmentName:  Segment Name : SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (Permission)_01,    
SegmentCount: 0        
},    
{    
SegmentId : 82394,    
SegmentName:  Segment Name : SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (Permission)_01,    
SegmentCount: 0        
}
]
```

Comment: Can  you show us what you've tried so far and where you're stuck?

Comment: Also is there no delimiter between segment count and the next segment ID? Can I assume it would be `/n` or something else?

Comment: yah you assume /n

Comment: I'm sure we can help solve this.  But StackOverflow is predicated on you doing your work first and then showing us where you got stuck.  It is not a code-writing service.

Comment: do you really want `Segment Name` as part of the value?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your useful suggestions and answers, it will help me lot learn new things. ex- Regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am considering your string with delimiter /n

```
var string="Segment Id : 82394 | Segment Name : SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (Permission)_01 | Segment Count : 0 /n  Segment Id : 82395 | Segment Name : SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (LeadYoung)_02 | Segment Count : 0"


var separatedAsArray=string.split('/n')
var string2=separatedAsArray.toString();

//Output of the above two lines
"Segment Id : 82394 | Segment Name : SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (Permission)_01 | Segment Count : 0 ,  Segment Id : 82395 | Segment Name : SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (LeadYoung)_02 | Segment Count : 0"


var formatedString = string2.split(',');

//Output of the above line is 
["Segment Id : 82394 | Segment Name : SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (Permission)_01 | Segment Count : 0 ", "  Segment Id : 82395 | Segment Name : SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (LeadYoung)_02 | Segment Count : 0"]


formatedString.forEach(function(element) {
var properties = element.split('|');
var obj = {};
properties.forEach(function(ele) {
    var keyValue = ele.split(':');
    obj[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
});
 console.log(obj)
});

//Output of the above code snippet is
{
  Segment Count : " 0 ",
  Segment Name : " SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (Permission)_01 ",
  Segment Id : " 82394 "
}
{
  Segment Id : " 82395 ",
  Segment Count : " 0",
  Segment Name : " SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (LeadYoung)_02 "
}
```

After getting the individual object store them in the array or anywhere you want...

Answer (score 1):

Hello check this version with javascript split() function that pushes every object to an array of objects:

```js
var str = "Segment Id : 82394 | Segment Name : SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (Permission)_01 | Segment Count : 0 Segment Id : 82395 |  Segment Name : SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (LeadYoung)_02 | Segment Count : 0 Segment Id : 82396 |   Segment Name : SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (LeadYoung)_03 | Segment Count : 0";
    let splitted = str.split("|");
    let nextId;
    let arrayOfObjects = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < splitted.length - 2; i = i + 2) {
      let id;
      if (i == 0) id = splitted[0].split(":")[1];
      if (i > 0) id = nextId;
      let name = splitted[i + 1].split(":")[1];
      let count = splitted[i + 2].split(':')[1].split(" ")[1];
      nextId = splitted[i + 2].split(':')[2];
      let singleObject = { SegmentId: null, SegmentName: null, segmentCount: null }
      singleObject.SegmentId = id;
      singleObject.SegmentName = name;
      singleObject.segmentCount = count;
      arrayOfObjects.push(singleObject);
    }
    console.log(arrayOfObjects);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I might proceed:

```js
const parse = (str) => 
  str .trim() .split (/\s*\n\s*/)
    .map (s => s .split (' | ') .map (s => s .split (' : ')))
    .map (row => row .map (([k, v]) => [k .replace (/\s+/, ''), isNaN (v) ? v : Number(v)]))
    .map (Object .fromEntries)
         
const str = `
Segment Id : 82394 | Segment Name : SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (Permission)_01 | Segment Count : 0
Segment Id : 82395 | Segment Name : SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (LeadYoung)_02 | Segment Count : 0
Segment Id : 82395 | Segment Name : SPA FIAT MAR 2020 LKADCLAKSC DEM (LeadYoung)_02 | Segment Count : 0
`

console .log (parse (str))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We start by trimming off any excess from the string, then split it on line-breaks (plus any space around them).  Then for each row, we split the fields on `|` and split the keys from the values on `:`.  In the next line, each key-value pair is converted: we remove spaces from the keys, and we convert values that look like numbers to numbers.  (You might need something more sophisticated if there are more fields or if, for instance, the `count` is supposed to be numeric but the `id` isn't.)  Finally, each row is converted into an object with `Object .fromEntries`.

This all assumes that you actually have line-breaks as per the comments.  If not, the initial split might need to be more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

I recommed using `String.split()` method. The documentation is here [Javascript Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
To illustrate, what it does:

```js
const string = "Name | Value";
var results = string.split("|");
console.log(results); // Array: ["Name ", " Value"]
```

In your case, you can start splitting the string by "\n" (Newline) then "|" and finally ":".

Hope this helps you with your problem!

Comment: Does you solution give him the desired result?

Comment: @SRana: It is at least a pointer in the right direction.  It's part of the solution I wrote but am not willing to share without seeing some effort from the OP.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, that makes sense. But this should not added be as an answer. It's not the solution so i would prefer this kind of direction needs to added in comment section with proper reference link.